# Tableau Desktop - Window_sum with fixed without effect of color markers

Tags: tableau-desktop

I have a problem that that shouldn't give much trouble, but I can't make the sense out of this.

I have a measure called m_test as follows:

```
WINDOW_SUM(ATTR({ FIXED [Period]: COUNT([ID])}),-([p_mvavg_num_periods]),0)
```

This is supposed to calculate the moving sum of the count of IDs with a parameter selection for the number of periods at the FIXED LOD for [Period].

My view has [m_test] at Columns Shelf, and [Period] at rows shelf. And so far, so good, the view show the correct values regardless of [p_mvavg_num_periods] selected.

However, when I put the column [Classification] as color markers AND [p_mvavg_num_periods] > 0, the view shows different values depending on the [Classification] as shown below:

[image: Example 1]

I recognize that this happens because the [Classification] = "Class3" only exists for [Period] = 2023-T2 and not for previous periods, but I assumed that using the Fixed [Period] would work because it would calculate at the [Period] level and would not be affected by [Classification] at the color markers.

How can I do this calculation without being affected by the color markers?

Constraints: Need to use the [p_mvavg_num_periods] as this parameter is being used for other purposes in my dashboards.

I have attached the [sample data source and sample twbx file](https://community.tableau.com/s/question/0D58b0000BU1zv7CQB/windowsum-with-fixed-without-effect-of-color-markers) for your consideration.

Answer (score 0):

To be clear, using `Fixed [Period]` is running your calculation at the `[Period]` level. `[Classification]` however seems to exist at the same or lower LOD. Inferring from your above image, each `[Period]` looks to have a `[Classification]`. So if you color on `[Classification]` your calculations will not be affected in computation, rather they will be affected in their grouping.

If this is simply a visual fix you want to implement, you can [define a custom color configuration via a calculated field](https://kb.tableau.com/articles/howto/creating-custom-color-scale-for-varying-ranges-of-date).

- A quick fix would be to write a calculated field say, `[Classification Colors]` to the tune of `IF [Classification] = "Class3" THEN "Class2" ELSE [Classification] END`
- Drag `[Classification Colors]` to *Color* in the Marks Pane.

**Note:** *Hard coding values is not best practice and if say a "Class4" ever showed up, you would need to edit the above calc. You can always futureproof your code from the get-go.*